# Failed to resize image vertically in Draft.js

Tags: javascript, draftjs, draft-js-plugins

I am using Draft.js plugin [Resizeable](https://www.draft-js-plugins.com/plugin/image).

I am trying to resize the image with original length-to-width ratio.

However, for the code below, when I use the mouse to resize by the bottom edge of the image, the cursor changed, but it failed to resize. It only works well at the left and right edge.

```
const resizeablePlugin = createResizeablePlugin({
  vertical: 'relative',
  horizontal: 'relative'
});
```

<kbd>[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ww58nv7zx8)</kbd>

After viewing the [source code](https://github.com/draft-js-plugins/draft-js-plugins/blob/master/draft-js-resizeable-plugin/src/createDecorator.js), I still didn't figure out what causes this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does not seem like developers of this plugin had provided this opportunity to change image size with saving ratio when you resize by the top or bottom edges. Configuration option `vertical: 'relative'` means that plugin should set `height` value in relative units (percents). You can check with devtools that when you try to resize your image `height` value does change. But we should change `width` value to reach the behaviour when we resize the image with saving ratio.

It can be achieved by rewriting the source code a bit. Check [this fork of your sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/n4718w1w24).

Check `createDecorator.js` it is the same file that is stored in `/node_modules/draft-js-resizeable-plugin/lib/createDecorator.js`. What did I change in it? Find `doDrag` function (I market with `// !` all strings that was added or changed):

```
...
var startWidth = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(pane).width, 10);
var startHeight = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(pane).height, 10);

var imageRect = pane.getBoundingClientRect(); // !
var imageRatio = imageRect.width / imageRect.height; // ! get image ratio

// Do the actual drag operation
var doDrag = function doDrag(dragEvent) {
  var width = startWidth + dragEvent.clientX - startX;
  var height = startHeight + dragEvent.clientY - startY;
  var block = store.getEditorRef().refs.editor;
  width = block.clientWidth < width ? block.clientWidth : width;
  height = block.clientHeight < height ? block.clientHeight : height;

  var widthForPercCalculation = (isTop || isBottom) && vertical === 'relative' ? height * imageRatio : width; // ! calculate new width value in percents

  var widthPerc = 100 / block.clientWidth * widthForPercCalculation; // !
  var heightPerc = 100 / block.clientHeight * height;

  var newState = {};
  if ((isLeft || isRight) && horizontal === 'relative') {
    newState.width = resizeSteps ? round(widthPerc, resizeSteps) : widthPerc;
  } else if ((isLeft || isRight) && horizontal === 'absolute') {
    newState.width = resizeSteps ? round(width, resizeSteps) : width;
  }

  if ((isTop || isBottom) && vertical === 'relative') {
    newState.width = resizeSteps ? round(widthPerc, resizeSteps) : widthPerc; // ! here we update width not height value
  } else if ((isTop || isBottom) && vertical === 'absolute') {
    newState.height = resizeSteps ? round(height, resizeSteps) : height;
  }
...
```

I think you can ask this plugin dev-team for add this feature or 
fork the project.

Comment: Really appreciate your help and time!